# How Create CRUD with Angular 5

Tags: angular, html, frontend, crud

I create CRUD with angular 5 (party front-end) for the role in my application, but the button save and button update don't work and this error :

```
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RoleComponent.html:47)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14640)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13787)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14138)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14070)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13793)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14138)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14096)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13788)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14138)
```

my code .html:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="reglist">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let registration of registrations; let i = index">
        <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
        <td>{{ registration.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ registration.lastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ registration.dob.day + '/' + registration.dob.month + '/' + registration.dob.year}}</td>
        <td>{{ registration.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ registration.country }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="onEdit(i)">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(i)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onNew()">New</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="regentry" *ngIf="showNew">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSave()"></form>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="firstname-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="regModel.firstName" name="firstName">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="lastname-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="regModel.lastName" name="lastName">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="dob-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">DOB</label>
  <div class="col-3 input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dob" [(ngModel)]="regModel.dob" ngbDatepicker #dob="ngbDatepicker">
    <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="dob.toggle()" type="button">
<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-email-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" [(ngModel)]="regModel.email" name="email">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-password-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" [(ngModel)]="regModel.password" name="password">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="city-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Country</label>
  <div class="col-10 dropdown" ngbDropdown myDrop="ngbDropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownManual" name="country" ngbDropdownToggle>{{regModel.country}}</button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownManual">
      <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="onChangeCountry(country)">{{country}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{submitType}}</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
```

and this .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';



class Registration {
  constructor(
    public firstName: string = '',
    public lastName: string = '',
    public dob: NgbDateStruct = null,
    public email: string = '',
    public password: string = '',
    public country: string = 'Select country'
  ) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-role',
  templateUrl: './role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./role.component.css']
})
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(

  ) {
    this.registrations.push(new Registration('Johan', 'Peter', { year: 1980, month: 5, day: 12 }, 'johan@gmail.com', 'johan123', 'UK'));
    this.registrations.push(new Registration('Mohamed', 'Tariq', { year: 1975, month: 12, day: 3 }, 'tariq@gmail.com', 'tariq123', 'UAE'));
    this.registrations.push(new Registration('Nirmal', 'Kumar', { year: 1970, month: 7, day: 25 }, 'nirmal@gmail.com', 'nirmal123', 'India')); }

  registrations: Registration[] = [];
  regModel: Registration;
  showNew: Boolean = false;
  submitType: string = 'Save';
  selectedRow: number;
  countries: string[] = ['US', 'UK', 'India', 'UAE'];

  onNew() {
    this.regModel = new Registration();
    this.submitType = 'Save';
    this.showNew = true;
  }

  onSave() {
    if (this.submitType === 'Save') {
      this.registrations.push(this.regModel);
    } else {
      this.registrations[this.selectedRow].firstName = this.regModel.firstName;
      this.registrations[this.selectedRow].lastName = this.regModel.lastName;
      this.registrations[this.selectedRow].dob = this.regModel.dob;
      this.registrations[this.selectedRow].email = this.regModel.email;
      this.registrations[this.selectedRow].password = this.regModel.password;
      this.registrations[this.selectedRow].country = this.regModel.country;
    }
    this.showNew = false;
  }

  onEdit(index: number) {
    this.selectedRow = index;
    this.regModel = new Registration();
    this.regModel = Object.assign({}, this.registrations[this.selectedRow]);
    this.submitType = 'Update';
    this.showNew = true;
  }

  onDelete(index: number) {
    this.registrations.splice(index, 1);
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.showNew = false;
  }

  onChangeCountry(country: string) {
    this.regModel.country = country;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Form tag is in wrong place. It should cover all the input fields.  what do you want with this line of code <div *ngIf="showNew">    <form ngSubmit)="onSave()"></form>

Comment: @SivaRmK, I create this tag for changes and also to add new roles, 
is its location wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem come for the line 47, which is:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="regModel.firstName" name="firstName">
```

Which is the first time Angular's trying to bind the value of `firstName` property of the `regModel` object to the input element, which is already `undefine`.

The solution is initalizing the `regModel` with an instance of class Registration.

You should initialize a value for the  `regModel: Registration` just like you did with `registrations: Registration[] = []`

For instance:

```
registrations: Registration[] = [];
regModel: Registration = {}; //or regModel: Registration = new Registration ()
```

Hopefully, that helps!

Comment: it's work, thank's my friend, but the button save and update don't works

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized regModel in constructor, just add following into constructor

```
this.regModel = new Registration();
```

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSave()">{{submitType}}</button>` call `onSave()` from button click

Comment: Or you should change Form tag place, all fields including buttons should inside form tag.

Comment: In case of "save" or "update"? Does `this.selectedRow` has any value in it?

Comment: party.ts means? I didn't get your question.

Comment: i want to say when i use dynamic data, do I modify the static data by what (in my example, I have a single dynamic element "RoleName")

Comment: You want to say that you have static data which you've pushed in `this.registrations` in `constructor`but you want it dynamic, right?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to change the static data by dynamic data (I want for example to add dynamic data or modifiers)

Comment: Okay, then you have to make a service to call your web API or web service, then inject that service into your constructor, then call your service method from `ngOnInit()`. A very simple service example to understand how it works https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_services.htm